# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0 in GA api

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Im using the below google analyics api code for authentication before sending request to GA but im getting error messages

> "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '',
>   line 0, position 0 in GA api"

while execute the request through 
`GAOuthService.Data.Ga.Get()` method

**My Authentcation Code:**

```
      var scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics, 
                                         AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsEdit, 
                                         AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsManageUsers,   
                                         AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly};    

        // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                , scopes
                                                                                , userName
                                                                                , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                , new FileDataStore("GoogleAnalytics.Auth.Store")).Result;

        var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                                               {
                                                   HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                                                   ApplicationName = "xyz",

                                               });
```

Comment: you forgot to post the code you are using for GAOuthService.Data.Ga.Get()  Authentication isn't giving you an error posting the code for that wont help.

Answer (score 1):

Using the code you have above the following is how a request should look.

```
var request = service.Data.Ga.Get("ga:8903098", "2014-01-01", "2014-01-01", "ga:sessions");
request.MaxResults = 1000;
GaData result = request.Execute();
```

Your authentication appears to be returning using the variable **service**.  Unless you are also authenticating with **GAOuthService** then calling `GAOuthService.Data.Ga.Get()`  probably wont work.

you need to remember to post all the code in question